# How to avoid negative resistance of current source in LTspice

Tags: current-source, ltspice, current-limiting, lm335

I'm trying to implement simple behavioural model of LMx34 devices. Circuit below tends to have negative resistance if supplied voltage drops below current source drop. How to avoid this? I prefer pure B-source solution for some reason.

[image]

Comment: You might want to specify which version of ltspice you use, since the new one might have some not yet widely known differences (in case someone tries to replicate and fails to do so)

Comment: I use LTspice IV for mac

Comment: Have you tried an IF(...) statement in your B-source?

Comment: I get an "timestamp too small" error.

Comment: If the original doesn't show a negative resistance and this one does, then it's, most probably, a glitch in the implementation. Where, I couldn't tell, but this much logic I can afford...